# Transitioning to Fastlane Match Duplicate Certificates CI

Tags: jenkins, xcodebuild, fastlane, in-house-distribution, fastlane-match

I am trying to transition my team to using Fastlane Match. I have it working on my local machine, but not on our CI (jenkins) machine. Our CI machine still has the old certificate installed on it and I assume this is causing the issue. When running through CI I get the error:

Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "match InHouse >bundle id<" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution: >org<".

My best guess is that gym is picking up the wrong cert when trying to verify the provisioning profile because both certs have the same name.

Is there a way to specify which cert to use by id or expiration date when archiving the build from gym/xcodebuild?

Deleting the old certificate is not a viable option because, as of now, we still need the old cert until our fastlane build is 100% stable and everyone has transitioned to using it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Luke! It's a bit obsolete SO question but anyway have you found solution for your issue related to certificates with the same name? I have the similar issue now and cannot find any information to solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify which cert to use in one of two ways:

1. In your fastfile with the export_options and provisioningProfiles option:

.

```
gym(
    ...
    export_options:{
        compileBitcode: false,
        signingStyle: "manual",
        provisioningProfiles:{
            "com.myapp.iosapp": "match AdHoc com.myapp.iosapp"
        }
```

2. Or in Xcode's Build Settings, by setting each of the certs manually:

[image]